# VC dimension of a class H that assigns 1 to at most k points or that assigns 0 to at most k points

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, vc-theory

Let X be a finite domain and k a number such that k≤|X|. Consider the hypothesis class

H:={h:|{x∈X:h(x)=1}|<=k or |{x∈X:h(x)=0}|<=k}.

Find VC dimension of H.

Comment: Is this a binary classification problem, where you're proposing some Boolean hypothesis over $x$ ? Would you like to describe the VC dimension of a simpler $h'$ which assigns 1 to at most $k$ points, and hence 0 to at least $|X| - k$ points? Perhaps an even [simpler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension#Examples) $h''$ which assigns 1 to _exactly_ $k$ points?